# Laravel 5.0 getting array with the values of 1 column from relation function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Mailgroup model with a relation to get the CommunicationType's like so:

```
$communicationTypes = $mailgroup->communicationTypes->toArray();
```

This returns:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
  array (size=3)
    'id' => int 9
    'mailgroup_id' => int 16
    'communication_type' => string 'a' (length=1)
1 => 
  array (size=3)
    'id' => int 10
    'mailgroup_id' => int 16
    'communication_type' => string 'b' (length=1)
2 => 
  array (size=3)
    'id' => int 11
    'mailgroup_id' => int 16
    'communication_type' => string 'c' (length=1)
```

My goal is to get this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
```

Now I've tried the following but all results in an error.

```
$communicationTypes = $mailgroup->communicationTypes()->communication_type->toArray();

$communicationTypes = $mailgroup->communicationTypes()->pluck('communication_type')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to iterate through the resulting array and create a new array from it. Without considering best practices or whether you should convert the collection to an array in this form first, to answer your question, something like:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($communicationTypes as $key => $item) {
     $newArray[$key] = $item['communication_type'];
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do something with eloquent and avoid writing an extra loop?